# How to index tables and pictures in Word so you can get a list of them automatically?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I'm writing *one of those things* where you have to provide a list of all the tables and pictures at the beginning of the text. I know how to insert caption for a picture, but I'm not sure as to how can I do that for a table or some miscellaus object, in a way that I can get a list of them all afterwards ?

Can anyone give a hint or two ?
*Usually I do these things manually, but this document is getting big.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this. It's taken from [an old MS support article](https://web.archive.org/web/20100626054203/http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-a-table-of-figures-HP005189297.aspx) (a more up-to-date version can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-table-of-figures-c5ea59c5-487c-4fb2-bd48-e34dd57f0ec1)).

1. Click where you want to insert the table of figures.
2. On the Insert menu, point to Reference, click Index and Tables, and then click the Table of Figures tab.
3. In the Caption label box, click the type of caption label you want to compile in the table of figures.
4. Do one of the following:

   - To use one of the available designs, click a design in the Formats box.
   - To design a custom table of figures layout, choose the options you want.
5. Select any other table of figures options you want.

Comment: Andy, thanks for answering. Ok, I understand how to get the table of figures. Could you just tell me how to "mark the table with a caption"?

Comment: Nwm, I got it ;)

Comment: The one time I used Word for a large document I tried to do everything anally correctly. So I was careful with using styles, ensuring that _keep with next_ was used appropriately, using headings appropriately, having an auto-generated ToC and ToF, references like _see above/see below/see Appendix X_... and I found that Word worked fine 98.7% of the time, but just went insanely wacky on occasion. It can be extremely frustrating: good luck!